# A form that adds a HTMl block to a static page

Tags: php, html, forms

I am trying to create a form that modifies a predefined block of html and then when they submit it it adds it to a html page.

For example: the form will add a product to the static listings page. you edit the title and price in a form, then when they click submit it adds the title and price to a predefined html block and adds that block to the html page. Does that make sense?

Comment: Sounds like you want to make a [Content Management System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_management_system)

Comment: Yes, I have been looking at very many CMS systems but none of them seem to do that? Or do they and I just don't know what I am looking for?

Comment: Take a look at these [CMS Systems](https://www.practicalecommerce.com/13-free-open-source-content-management-systems) that appear to be free. You can do this yourself but it requires front-end and back-end work. So you would need to be experienced with, for example, javascript, php, MySql. It can be done. I certainly am not trying to dissuade you from trying and learning. This may not be the best place to ask such a vague question. SO does a great job of helping people with coding issues. If you can't show some code, you are unlikely to get much assistance.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance. I will keep that in mind when asking further questions